# Seeing clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name on Java

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, selenium, webdriver

Writing a threaded java 1.7 program on OSX, and I'm seeing this error message pop up and spam my console once it creates an object with the selenium stuff inside of it. I am using java.util.Random in a different class, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I tried to do a google search for that error message, but didn't get anything that seemed relevant.

Console:

```
    Posting To SAASAPP
Entered postToSAASAPP
Starting SAAS APP Library
clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
```

?Relevant? Code

```
System.out.println("Entered postToSAASAPP");
    Random generator = new Random();
    int postIndex = generator.nextInt() % PostDictionary.size();

    System.out.println("Starting SAAS APP Library");

    SAASAPPLibrary SP = new SAASAPPLibrary();
    SP.setup();
    SP.login("email@someaddress.com", "somepassword");
    SP.changeGroup("Soak");
    SP.post(PostDictionary.get(postIndex));
    System.out.println("Posted to SAASAPP: " + PostDictionary.get(postIndex));
```

I did some process of elimination into SP.setup(); and found that the following is the code that is causing the clock_get_time() failed: (ipc/rcv) invalid name issue.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```